# Get two letter country code in Apex method

Tags: apex, country-and-state

I want to write an Apex method that takes a country name as input and returns the equivalent two letter country code (ISO A2). Is there a way to write it without explicitly hard coding all countries and code in the method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using [State and Country Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0)? If so, you can just describe any standard country picklist (e.g. Contact.CountryCode). Otherwise, you can always load the list of countries into a [Custom Metadata Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=0), or using [Custom Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_about.htm&type=0), which allows you to customize the values that are contained in the list.